# Internet explorer wrapping words different in textareas than divs

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, word-wrap

In Internet explorer (tested in IE10), it looks like inside a textarea, a space after a word is treated as it would be a part of the word itself when it comes to wrapping. Please refer to the following images:
[image]
[image]
On the left side, you see the textarea, on the right side you see a div with the same content as the textarea. In the first image, as expected the word "vero" fits well in the line of "voluptua". Then after adding another word (or even only a space), "vero" appears on a new line. But only in the textarea, not in the div. I want to calculate the height of the textarea, so it is important to me, that the word wrapping/breaking behaviour is the same.

I already tried to give the textarea and div the same word-wrap, white-space, line-break, -ms-word-break, word-break and -ms-hyphens property, but without any positive result.

Has anyone yet had to deal with this problem and got a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {  
    var txt = $('#comments'),  
        hiddenDiv = $(document.createElement('div')),  
        content = null;  

    txt.addClass('txtstuff');  
    hiddenDiv.addClass('hiddendiv common');  

    $('body').append(hiddenDiv);  

    txt.on('keyup', function () {  

        content = $(this).val();  

        content = content.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');  
        hiddenDiv.html(content + '<br class="lbr">');  

        $(this).css('height', hiddenDiv.height());  

    });​  
});
```

CSS:

```
        textarea {  
        width: 500px;  
        min-height: 50px;  
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;  
        font-size: 13px;  
        color: #444;  
        padding: 5px;  
    }  

    .noscroll {  
        overflow: hidden;  
    }  

.hiddendiv {  
    display: none;  
    white-space: pre-wrap;  
    width: 500px;  
    min-height: 50px;  
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;  
    font-size: 13px;  
    padding: 5px;  
    word-wrap: break-word;  
}
```